# Optidef Environment

Tags: text, optidef

I am using the optidef package in writing optimization problems. For example, I am using the following formulation:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\newcommand{\mbf}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypcap}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[short]{optidef}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\semiHuge{\@setfontsize\semiHuge{23}{28}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\green}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\1}{\mathbbmss{1}}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

     \begin{mini!}
            {\boldsymbol{w},\boldsymbol{\Phi}}    {\| \boldsymbol{w}\|^2 }
            {\label{eq:minp}}{}
            \addConstraint{|(\boldsymbol{h}_r^H \boldsymbol{\Theta} \boldsymbol{G} + \boldsymbol{h}_d^H)\boldsymbol{w}| \geq \gamma \sigma^2} \label{eq:snd}
            \addConstraint{\Phi_n \in \mathcal{F}, \forall n}\label{eq:pha}
        \end{mini!}
\end{document}
```

and I am getting this:

[image]

My question is how to make the word "min" or "max"  not in italic mode?

Comment: Welcome to the tex.se. You can use `\max ` (i.e.  `\min`).

Comment: Please post a complete code. This is not the normal result, so there's something else in your code  that produces the italic letters

Comment: Thank you @Sebastiano Where to use the \max? I do not think it is applicable to optidef environment.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for your reply, I have edited the post and included the complete code.

Comment: I've  found the culprit: package `breqn`. Do you  really need it? It is not recommended, as it seems to have quite some problems.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks a lot! solved my problem :)

Comment: B.t.w., the `epsfig`package is obsolete – graphicx does the job. You also can simply your preamble: needless to load (twice!) array here, since you load `tabularx`, as well as `amsfonts`  (loaded by `amssymb`). Last observation: `hyperref` should be loaded last, with very few exceptions – `hypcap` is one of them (and `cleveref`, if you ever happen to load both).

Comment: I'm glad I helped you.